# Null Pointer Exception(not solved) and Unable to map WSResponse to Result in play 2.4 (this part solved. i guess)

Tags: java, asynchronous, playframework, playframework-2.0, java-8

I am trying to write a simple application in Play2.4. I want to get a page and display it on my localhost which will act as a proxy. Below is my action in the controller:

```
public class Proxy extends Controller{
    @Inject WSClient ws;

    public Promise<Result> index(String url){
        WSRequest request = ws.url(url);
        //Promise<WSResponse> responsePromise = request.get();
        return Promise.promise(() -> request.get())
                .map((WSResponse wsresponse) -> ok(wsresponse.getBody()).as("text/html"));
    }
}
```

I am getting an error `no suitable method found for map((WSRespons[...]tml"))` . i am very new to Play as well as Java8. Could you please help me out here or point me in the right direction.

Also, should we use WSResponse or just Response. The documentation is very scarce in these regards.

I basically want the above task to be done in async. Thanks

PS: I have been following this link https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaAsync and https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaAsync.

**PPS. AS suggested in the comments by @MonCalamari i did use** `return request.get().map((r) -> ok(r.getBody()).as("text/html"));`
However now i get a strange

```
Execution exception
[NullPointerException: scheme]
```

at the line

`return request.get().map((r) -> ok(r.getBody()).as("text/html"));`

I have tried going through the docs and other sources as well bu to no avail. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Unable to get any answers...went through the stack trace but could not get anything... Below is the stack trace if someone is interested.

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[NullPointerException: scheme]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:254) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:180) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:179) [play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:212) [play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:94) [play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$9$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:158) [play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$9$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:155) [play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:215) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:191) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Failure.recover(Try.scala:215) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:324) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:324) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.executeScheduled(Execution.scala:109) [play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:71) [play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:23) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40) [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.11.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397) [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.11.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: scheme
    at com.ning.http.client.uri.Uri.<init>(Uri.java:56) ~[async-http-client-1.9.21.jar:na]
    at com.ning.http.client.uri.Uri.create(Uri.java:32) ~[async-http-client-1.9.21.jar:na]
    at com.ning.http.client.uri.Uri.create(Uri.java:25) ~[async-http-client-1.9.21.jar:na]
    at com.ning.http.client.RequestBuilderBase.setUrl(RequestBuilderBase.java:307) ~[async-http-client-1.9.21.jar:na]
    at com.ning.http.client.RequestBuilder.setUrl(RequestBuilder.java:165) ~[async-http-client-1.9.21.jar:na]
    at play.libs.ws.ning.NingWSRequest.buildRequest(NingWSRequest.java:401) ~[play-java-ws_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.libs.ws.ning.NingWSRequest.execute(NingWSRequest.java:394) ~[play-java-ws_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.libs.ws.ning.NingWSRequest.execute(NingWSRequest.java:389) ~[play-java-ws_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.libs.ws.ning.NingWSRequest.get(NingWSRequest.java:272) ~[play-java-ws_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at controllers.Proxy.index(Proxy.java:46) ~[classes/:2.4.0]
    at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Routes.scala:157) ~[classes/:na]
    at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Routes.scala:157) ~[classes/:na]
    at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$5.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:139) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$14$$anon$3$$anon$1.invocation(HandlerInvoker.scala:127) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:65) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.http.DefaultHttpRequestHandler$1.call(DefaultHttpRequestHandler.java:20) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$7.apply(JavaAction.scala:85) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$7.apply(JavaAction.scala:85) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:40) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:70) [play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext.execute(HttpExecutionContext.scala:32) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$.apply(Future.scala:31) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$.apply(Future.scala:492) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at play.core.j.JavaAction.apply(JavaAction.scala:85) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:105) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:105) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:104) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:103) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:103) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:96) ~[play_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:524) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:524) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:560) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:560) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Iteratee.scala:536) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Iteratee.scala:536) ~[play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You dont have to wrap return statement with `Promise.promise()`. `request.get()` already returns promise: `return request.get().map((r) -> ok(r.getBody()).as("text/html"));`

Comment: @MonCalamari also, could you guide me to the proper documentation if these topics... teach a man to fish :) especially Play2.4. The regex thing i will try to look on my own...Thanks

Comment: This is how your routes should look like: `GET /proxy/:url @controllers.Proxy.index(url:String)` - mind `GET` in uppercase and `@` prefix since you use dependency injection.

Comment: @MonCalamari The mapping worked now but i am getting a null pointer exception at the return

Comment: @MonCalamari Yes...i just fixed the typo...i apologize for jumping the gun there...Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second part of the question was answered by @Mon Calamari.WE need to use `return request.get().map((r) -> ok(r.getBody()).as("text/html"));` . As for the first part, the issue was 2 part.

Check whether we have valid url or not. There are a lot of ways to do    that. I did with the following simple approach.

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.yoursite.com/");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.connect();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // the URL is not in a valid form
} catch (IOException e) {
    // the connection couldn't be established
}
```

And then, the main culprit was in my `routes` file.

```
GET     /proxy/:url         controllers.Proxy.index(url:String) 
GET     /proxy               controllers.Proxy.index(url:String)
```

The first one was causing error. I replace it with query parameters as show in the second line and everything worked out fine.